# Publish/Subscribe pattern using OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<T>()

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, callback, publish-subscribe

I have a WCF Service which implements the Callback pattern as shown in [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). 
Binding: `wsDualHttpBinding`. It works fine.

As you can see in the Example paragraph, I get the "callback channel" (so, from Server to Client) using this code:

```
OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<T>()
```

I used Callback pattern to implement a Publish/Subscribe mechanism. To do this, I store every "callback channel" into a list and use it to contact subscribers when a publish event fires. Clients can subscribe to Service, calling a specific procedure.
After some tests, all seems to work fine.

However, I have some questions: is this the right way to get and use "callback channels"? Is there an expiration time of channels? Are there any limits in this implementation? Does `GetCallbackChannel` method have some limits (i.e. how it works, exactly)? Subscribers are mostly dynamic Clients, so what Server have to do when a subscriber breaks down?

I work for the first time with Callback and Publish/Subscribe model, so I need some guidelines.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you John. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Everything regarding timeouts or this type of behavior is to be investigated into the web.config file probably. The `serviceModel` configuration tag provides all information regarding settings of a particular binding, I would suggest you to look there to begin with.